# Ruby on rails - AngularJs Possibly unhandled refection - reason: unauthorized, no credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, devise

I'm clueless about this issue that's happening to me. Any page I go into I'm getting this error in my js console:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"reason":"unauthorized","errors":["No credentials"]}
```

I recently installed Devise-token-auth and Ng-token-auth (which I have really bad time lol) to handle authentication. But I cannot find what I did wrong, I supposed is something about my ruby configuration. Does anyone know what could it be?

I know is not too much of imformation, but I'm complety lost. Let me know if you need something else.

EDIT: That error shows up because I haven't log in to my api... but in my site there are a few places where the user doesn't need to be log in. How can I handle this behaivor? (exaple: in my sign in page, shouldn't be expected to the user to be already log in...)

Answer (score 1):

After a while I figured it out. Ng-token-auth has an automatically validation that checks every load page if the user is log in. I have change the configuration like this:

```
app.config(function($authProvider) {
       $authProvider.configure({
           apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1',
           validateOnPageLoad: false <-----
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS shows you errors like this when you've an unhandled promise rejection in your app. This may be in your code, or in a library you've used in your code. A quick Google search results that users started facing this when they upgraded to Angular v1.5.9.

To solve this, you need to handle the promise rejections. For example, you can do this with `$http` service as follows:

```
$http({ ... })
  .then(function() {
    // .. code here for promise resolve ..
  }, function() {
    // .. code here for promise reject ..
  });
```

Another thing you code do is to configure your app to disable this error entirely.

```
app.config(function($qProvider) {
  $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
});
```